# MS ACCESS VBA ORDER BY CASE When

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I a lot of `orders in my Factory`.

Our regular time to finish our job is 10 days but sometimes we promise to the customer that it will be shorter (lets assume 5 days).

I tried to build an SQL that order by the `minimum Date of the two columns`:

```
SELECT id, Status, DeliveryDate, PromiseDate
FROM CustomerOrderT
WHERE Status > 2 and Status <7 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DeliveryDate > PromiseDate then PomiseDate ELSE DeliveryDate END;
```

But i get a problem message from ms access. maybe write it correctly
The problem massage attached

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Access you have to use IIF instead of Case like this:

```
SELECT id, Status, DeliveryDate, PromiseDate
FROM CustomerOrderT
WHERE Status > 2 and Status <7 
ORDER BY IIF(DeliveryDate > PromiseDate, PromiseDate, DeliveryDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help
That is Close, but if i need to order on each case by two columns how should i write it?
For example:
ORDER BY IIF(DeliveryDate > PromiseDate, (PromiseDate DeliveryDate) , (DeliveryDate PromiseDate));

This not working

Comment: This makes no sense. There is one column only. Please rephrase.

Comment: The second order by would make no difference to the outcome. Only if you want to order by a 3rd column when PromiseDate and DeliveryDate are equal. Then you would add the 3rd column behind the whole IIF with a ,